# I'm trying to further automate calculations on timesheets, depending on gaps sizes between jobs

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am trying to automate a timesheet.
The employee gets paid for gaps of 30 minutes or less.
They do not get paid for gaps of greater than 30 minutes.
They may do 1 job per day or as many as 6 jobs per day.
Therefore the calculation is not just from their start time to their finish time each day.
[image]
**The last column in the image shows my desired result.**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wcZ2k3pc5t7Rco688Ja2LrP4PIkOpwcA5IjWBQvS2Gs/copy

Comment: by gaps you mean gaps of work or gaps between two jobs? also, employee will still be paid for each job (?) so this is all about extra payment for time in between jobs right?

Comment: yes that is right, sorry i didn't make that clear. The employee gets paid for all jobs and gaps of 30 mins or less between jobs, but if the gap between jobs is greater than 30 mins they get paid for the job but not the gap time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete range I13:K and use in cell I13:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H13:H="",,ROUND((H13:H-G13:G)*24, 2)))
```

use in cell J13:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A13:A<>"")+(H13:H=""),,ROUND((G13:G-H12:H)*24, 2)))
```

and use in cell K13:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H13:H="",,I13:I+IF(J13:J<=0.5, J13:J, )))
```

[image]